# How can I test what kind of server specs do my website require for 1000 concurrent users?

Tags: mysql, php, hosting, benchmark

My website is similar to this. Same concept.
http://www.solomid.net/

I expect 1K concurrent connections to my website.

The website;

- Uses Laravel 3,
- Partially Memcaches queries,
- Mostly CRUD work,
- AJAX enabled.

I currently host it on a random shared web hosting for development purposes.

I had a server like this before, for hosting a private game server, and we had like 400+ concurrent players playing + forum + website

- Quad Core 2.66Ghz HT Lynnfield (X3450)
- 8GB DDR3 ECC
- 2 x 120GB Intel Solid State
- 100MBPS Unmetered
- Windows 2008 Enterprise Edition 64 Bit
- 105 USD/a month

The only difference is: I'll use linux now. No more game server, just the website at port 80.

Such box would work for 1K concurrency? Would it be overkill?

Also, how can I make calculations for the requirements?

Comment: impossible for us to tell without a lot more details.. we have no idea of the average cpu us per request and the average ram/IO use per request. There is no set answer to this.. You have to know how your app behaves and what it needs.

Comment: PHP's XDebug information may work?

Comment: it might.. i think generally you would be better off creating your app in a fashion where the app server can scale out horizontally so you can deploy to something like AWS and scale up that way. Those server specs you gave are awful RAM wise.. I'd give a guess you're gonna swap out well before hitting 1k concurrent users with only 1k of ram. More so since you are running windows as a server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use stress test and benchmark tools such as `siege` and Apache's `ab`.

Your server should has ab if you're using Apache as web server. What you should to do is, running the ab tool with right parameters ( preferably from remote server ) and watch the load on your server and your site.

You can find a good explanation and examples at http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-performance-benchmarks-a-web-server.html